# Do I need to buy seed packets from Crazy Dave every time I want to use them?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

Crazy Dave just opened shop and he sports two very interesting "plants": twin sunflowers and gatling peas. However, I'm afraid that the price tag of $5k is *per use*, rather than "buy once, use forever," in which case the price tag is way too steep for all practical purposes.

Which is it?

Comment: I really hate when games, or any program for that matter, don't make things like this explicitly clear.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is buy once use forever, once you buy them they will always be available to you in your arsenal of extremely deadly plants.

Comment: If I recall correctly, Dave's selling you *seed packets* that you can choose to add to your loadout when you start a level.  The seed packets apparently contain unlimited seeds.

Comment: Yeah as you unlock the seeds you can select them when you're preparing your aresenal for a level. You can also purchase upgrades (which are place on top of regular plants) and extra seed slots to bring more plants to the level.

Comment: Making a complement to @Emerica's answer: Every day you can buy the plants AGAIN (if you want), every day crazy Dave will replace the plants in the shop (00:00 am). So you can fill your garden with sunflowers to 'farm' some money, if you want. a good start is get ONE SIDE of Crazy Dave sunflowers, and get the others spots from drops plants. (Then you can replace the Sunflowers from Crazy Dave after a while) is a good idea keep 2 slots empty to get new plants.

Comment: @MichelAyres pssst, this is not Google Plus. If you want to mention people, use the at-sign :)

Comment: Why would he sell you packets of infinite seeds for a one time cost? Because he's CRAAAAAAAZY!

Answer (score 2):

The twin sunflowers and gatling peas are plant cards you can buy from Crazy Dave.  When you buy these cards they are available at the start of the stage just like any plant card you've previously gotten by completing a stage.

In my playthrough, I bought the twin sunflowers when it was available.  It takes 150 sunlight to upgrade an existing sunflower to a twin sunflower.  You'd use this when you have abundant sunlight and scarce land.  It takes 6 sun cycles to pay for itself, compared to 2 sun cycles for just putting another sunflower.  In order to use it, it must be selected at the start of the stage and this costs 1 plant choice.  Given the sun cycle cost and the plant choice cost, just planting sunflowers would have worked better so far.  Saving for another plant selection slot would have been a better choice (I'm on the second night).

Answer (score 1):

Once you buy or earn any plant in Plants vs Zombies, it stays in your inventory forever. Same thing with pool cleaners, extra slots and bought minigames.

Answer (score 0):

Most things in crazy dave's shop are buy once use forever. All plants, cleaners, and minigames are buy once use forever. So, don't be scared to buy something from the shop. Fertilelizer, bug spray, and garden rakes are the only stuff that need to be bought again. P.S. please don't just read this, also read others if I miss out anything. P.P.S You will need cob cannon, gloom shrooms, twin sunflowers, and winter melons to survive far in survival endless. Trust me.